# How to switch to a different UITabBarItem on UIButton touch up inside

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a `UITabBarController` as my `MainWindow.xib`. I have 3 tab bar items on the tab bar. On the second tab bar item, i have placed a `UIButton`. When the user taps the button, i want to be able to switch to the first tab bar item and display the view loaded there. How would i do this programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UITabBacController`'s [`selectedViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController) property if you have a reference to the view controller you want to switch to, or you can use [`selectedIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex) if your tabs have a static order and you know which index to switch to.